# Two separate navbars with ScrollSpy?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy, affix

im building a "one page" website with two different navbars, one for desktop and the other for small screen sizes. The links in both navbars are same, just the appearance is different. My problem is that i havent find a way to scrollspy both of them, i tried this way but it didnt work:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar, .mobinavi" data-offset="0">
```

Heres the HTML:

```
<!-- NAVIGOINTI -->
<div class="container hidden-xs">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 navilaatikko">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top paanavi" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="140">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<span class="navbar-brand"></span>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="#sulka">Sulka</a></li>
<li><a href="#tapahtumat">Tapahtumat</a></li>
<li><a href="#galleria">Galleria</a></li>
<li><a href="#yhteystiedot-palaute">Yhteystiedot &amp; Palaute</a></li>
<li><a href="#henkilokunta">Henkilökunta</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="visible-xs mobinavi" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="140">
<a href="#sulka">Sulka</a>
<a href="#tapahtumat">Tapahtumat</a>
<a href="#galleria">Galleria</a>
<a href="#yhteystiedot-palaute">Yhteystiedot &amp; Palaute</a>
<a href="#henkilokunta">Henkilökunta</a>
</div>
<!-- /NAVIGOINTI -->
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't possible unless you modify the JS: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10251

Comment: Why don't you just use the same nav bar? Is there something stopping you?